# Cannot resolve symbol inside JAR imported in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar

I am trying to work with a jar which is of a previous project that has been properly tested and works fine.
I even decompiled the jar inside Android Studio and ran it and it worked fine as can be seen below:[image]

But the problem is this(HashTableClass.java and HashNodeClass.java are decompiled from the jar):[image]

Only HashTableClass is being identified and all the other classes are not being identified

[image: This is my build.gradle]

My imported jar file contains multiple packages.Things that I have tried to get out of this mess:
1.Invalidate Cache/Restart
2.Sync Project with Gradle Files

One solution is explicit typing of the package name before the type name in the java files of the jar but that doesn't seem to be a good solution.

My question is: **How do I stop this "cannot resolve symbol" mess in my JAR effectively?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some minor changes in the source files in the JAR and then imported a new JAR and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

i was using the jsoup Jar file and that happened,I solved the problem by removing it from ddependencies and adding it again